# Libgdx Texture change

Tags: java, libgdx, android, textures, scene2d

I have been working for several days to try and figure out how to change a texture whenever a scene2d Table is clicked in libgdx, I am using pixmaps to dynamically change the textures colors instead of changing the texture completely.

everything works fine when i detect key presses so whenever i press 1 the color of the players hair changes to a random color but now i want it to happen when i press a Table.

to change the texture i use this method

```
public static Texture genDynamicTexture(String path, HashMap<String,Color> colors) {

    //load texture from asset handler
    Texture texture = GameUtils.getGame().manager.get(path,Texture.class);

    //create pixmap from texture
    if(!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
        texture.getTextureData().prepare();
    }
    //transfer pixel data from gpu to cpu
    Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();

    //grey-scale colors
    Color gsHair = toColor(207,31,201);
    Color gsSkin = toColor(207,97,31);
    Color gsShirt1 = toColor(39,207,31);
    Color gsShirt2 = toColor(65,65,160);
    Color gsPants = toColor(90,9,22);
    Color gsShoe1 = toColor(253,255,66);
    Color gsShoe2 = toColor(43,58,50);
    Color black = toColor(0,0,0);

    //loop through pixels in the pixmap
    for(int x = 0; x < pixmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < pixmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            int pixelColor = pixmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if(pixelColor != 0 && pixelColor != Color.rgba8888(black)) {
                if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsHair)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("hair"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsSkin)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("skin"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsShirt1)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("shirt1"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsShirt2)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("shirt2"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsPants)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("pants"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsShoe1)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("shoe1"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }else if(pixelColor == Color.rgba8888(gsShoe2)) {
                    pixmap.setColor(colors.get("shoe2"));
                    pixmap.drawPixel(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //transfer pixel data from cpu to gpu
    Texture tex = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
    return tex;


}
```

like i said everything works fine if it is a key press but when i detect it using a Table it does not work ( i have already added it to the stage and am calling stage.act() and stage.draw() )

```
color.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            characterPack.reloadSpriteSheet("Players/greyscale-player.png", 2, 2, characterPack.colors, "skin");
        }
    });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by resetting what frame of the texture region was being rendered so in my code it was

```
characterPack.skin = characterPack.frames[0];
```

another option i found was i had my direction set to UNUSED so once i set it to down it updated itself.

the result reloads the colors to change the textures colors based on what options the user clicks.